# JQueryUI Autocomplete - Trigger on all events

Tags: php, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using JQuery UI Autocomplete to pull records from a caller database. This works fine for records that are in the database but I want to improve handling for new records.

For example, if a user chooses a name from a suggestion, I use the return id later in the form. This works fine.  If the value is not found in suggestions I am struggling to trigger the script since it is currently triggered from a select event, and there doesn't appear to be a onblur event for this function which I think is what I'm after. I'm new to JQuery and have already spent a day trying to sort it.

Code so far is:

```
$("#contact_name").autocomplete({  
            source: "get-caller-names.php",
            minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
                $('#contact_id').val(ui.item.id);
                $('#contact_name').val(ui.item.name);
                $('#contact_email').val(ui.item.email);
                $('#contact_phone').val(ui.item.phone);
                $('#contact_addr').val(ui.item.address);
                }              
        });
```

All suggestions welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not add a new handler for change eg:

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
    select: function(event, ui) { ... },
    change: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew - I'd just got it working as two separate functions but this way is much tidier.

Answer (score 1):

Code in case others have the same issue...

```
// auto-suggest jqueryui
$("#contact_name").autocomplete({
    source: "GetCallerNames.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
    $('#contact_id').val(ui.item.id);
    $('#contact_name').val(ui.item.name);
    $('#contact_email').val(ui.item.email);
    $('#contact_phone').val(ui.item.phone);
    $('#contact_addr').val(ui.item.address);
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'GetCallerNames.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {term:$(this).val()},
        success: function(data) {
            if (data!=null&&data!='') {
            $('#contact_id').val(data[0].id);
            $('#contact_email').val(data[0].email);
            $('#contact_phone').val(data[0].phone);
            $('#contact_addr').val(data[0].address);
            }
        }
        });
    }

    });
```